# ASP.NET Core 6 Web API : separate admin and client controllers

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

I am trying to create an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API and I got a problem:

[image]

As you can see, I have my models and database context in a `models` folder, and in `controllers`, I was trying to separate the client and the admin controllers. But I am kinda stuck here, I am thinking of using areas, but one problem came up: since in "areas", assuming I create an "areas/admin", I also have to create `models`, `controllers` folders too, but I want all the client and admin controllers to use the same models in a common `models` folder, because both client and admin controllers will use some of the same models in `models` folder.

So how can I separate the admin and client controllers while still using all the models in `models` folder for both? I looked for a solution, but none of them seem to answer my problem, please help :(

Comment: Can't you just create two subfolders `Admin` and `Client` in your `Controllers` folder, and put the individual controllers into one of these two subfolders?

Comment: @marc_s i havent though about it yet, so i dont really know will it work

Comment: @FalAn You can move ( and the most people do)  model files even in a different propject, not just folders. If you use  the layers (that is higly recommended )  models are usually kept in a separate EF project

Comment: @Serge i dont quite get it, can you explain it further please?

Comment: @FalAn I see you have your EF code in the same project  where is a front end. I highly recommend you to create a separate project for model and EF . In this case you can use model from any place in your solution.